# Canvas scaling retains pixel size

Tags: android, image-processing, scaling

I'm trying to do some image processing on the camera preview, but being too slow I under sample time image and do the processing on a smaller scale. Then I overlay the processed (thresholded) image over the preview. My problem is that when I scale the smaller image to fit the camera preview the pixels stay the same size... I would like to see some big pixels due to the scaling, but I can't.

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/svPreview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/svOverlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the thread that gets the camera preview image bytes and does the thresholding:

```
class PathThread extends Thread implements PreviewCallback
{
    private final int width, height;
    private final SurfaceHolder holder;
    private Canvas overlayCanvas;
    private int samples = 8;

    final private float scale;
    final private Paint red, blue, yellow;

    public PathThread(int canvasWidth, int canvasHeight, SurfaceView canvasView)
    {
        // This is how much smaller image I want
        width = canvasWidth / samples;
        height = canvasHeight / samples;
        holder = canvasView.getHolder();

        // Scale to fit the camera preview SurfaceView
        scale = (float) canvasView.getWidth() / height;

        // No smoothing when scaling please
        yellow = new Paint();
        yellow.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ffbb33"));
        yellow.setAntiAlias(false);  
        yellow.setDither(false);  
        yellow.setFilterBitmap(false);
    }

    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
    {
        overlayCanvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        overlayCanvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);
        overlayCanvas.scale(scale, scale);

        // Do the image processing and make a [samples] times smaller image
        // Boring, pseudo-optimized, per-pixel thresholding process

        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(overlayCanvas);
    }
}
```

This is the result:

[image: Scaled overlay pixels are of original size]

I'm aware that it's a little bit offset, but that's the least of my problems.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution:

After 2 more days of searching it was quite simple, but not very easy to find/understand:

With the holder of the SurfaceView where I draw I had to call this:

```
canvasHolder.setFixedSize(width, height);
```

I experimented with different values and found what I needed. This makes *big pixels*.